# Last character appears in the begining of line

Tags: linux, bash

Running the follow `echo $dnsDefinedUrl,$dnsResolvableHost,$dnsDefinedHost,1`
returns:

`,1d-ldn-uat.gb.derkb.com,ln2i32.zineta.com,[ln2i32.zineta.com]`

You will note the 1 at the beginning of the output. But should be at the end of the output.

i expect return to be `,d-ldn-uat.gb.derkb.com,ln2i32.zineta.com,[ln2i32.zineta.com],1`

Comment: `$dnsDefinedHost` obviously has a carriage return (`\r`) at the end.   You could use `tr` to remove carriage returns.

Comment: Use `dos2unix` to fix the file that you read these variables from.

Comment: See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) for more info and options for removing the carriage returns.

Comment: Thank you guys. @Barmar dos2unix fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```sh
echo $dnsDefinedUrl,$dnsResolvableHost,$dnsDefinedHost,1 | sed 's/\r//g'
```